# Script to compress all pdf files in a directory

Tags: python, pdf, ghostscript

I wish to compress all pdf files in a directory using ghostscript.
I thought of using python to read files 
and the gs command that compress pdf is

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
for path, dirs, files in os.walk("/home/mario/books"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".pdf"):
            filename = os.path.join(root, file)
            gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH  -dQUIET -sOutputFile=file filename
```

This gives syntax error at "/screen",
For a single file below command works fine

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH  -dQUIET -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

Could someone help me correcting this script or alternate solution?

Comment: You need to call a python function that executes programs. Check out `subprocess.call`. Also, you are using the wrong variable name when gluing the filename together, it should be `filename = os.path.join(path, file)`.

Comment: [`find ... -exec`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) might be a simpler option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for suggestion  tdelaney I tried subprocess.call which helped. Below is the code solved the problem.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import subprocess
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
for file in files:
    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
      filename = os.path.join(root, file)
      arg1= '-sOutputFile=' +"v"+ file
      p = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/gs', '-sDEVICE=pdfwrite', '-dCompatibilityLevel=1.4', '-dPDFSETTINGS=/screen', '-dNOPAUSE', '-dBATCH',  '-dQUIET', str(arg1), filename], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
      print (p.communicate())
```

Also find ... -exec is good option for shell script though.

Comment: I can`t get this to work on Windows 7. Is it a different command