# Python script to compress all pdf files in a directory on Windows 7

Tags: python, pdf, python-3.x, compression, ghostscript

Following the code sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27111760/script-to-compress-all-pdf-files-in-a-directory), I have the code below that is supposed to compress files in a directory using Ghostscript. The code compresses the files but then when I open the files, I do not see any content at all. I only want the files to be compressed. I don`t want the content to be erased.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import subprocess

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\comp"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".pdf"):
            filename = os.path.join(root, file)
            print (filename)
            arg1= '-sOutputFile=' + file
            p = subprocess.Popen(['C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.15/bin/gswin64c.exe',
                                  '-sDEVICE=pdfwrite', 
                                  '-dCompatibilityLevel=1.4', 
                                  '-dPDFSETTINGS=/screen', '-dNOPAUSE', 
                                  '-dBATCH', '-dQUIET', str(arg1), filename], 
                                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            print (p.communicate())
```

Comment: Do you get the same results running the process manually at the command prompt in a Windows console? If you can't see any content how do you know it what it did to the files?

Comment: The pdfwrite device doesn't 'compress' PDF files, it makes brand new ones. It looks to me like you are making the input and output filenames the same, you *cannot* do that. When you make the input and output the same, the first thing it does is open a file with the destination name, overwriting the original file, and leading to a 0 byte output file. NB I don't speak Python so I could be mistaken, it would be more obvious to me if you would quote the actual Ghostscript command line.

Comment: @KenS Thanks for your suggestion on changing the filename. I did that and it worked. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue following @KenS suggestion of giving the output file a different name and this worked.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import subprocess

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\comp"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".pdf"):
            filename = os.path.join(root, file)
            print (filename)
            arg1= '-sOutputFile=' + "c" +  file #added a c to the filename
            p = subprocess.Popen(['C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.15/bin/gswin64c.exe',
                                  '-sDEVICE=pdfwrite', 
                                  '-dCompatibilityLevel=1.4', 
                                  '-dPDFSETTINGS=/screen', '-dNOPAUSE', 
                                  '-dBATCH', '-dQUIET', str(arg1), filename], 
                                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            print (p.communicate())
```